# Angularjs checkbox multiple filter using JSON data

Tags: html, json, angularjs

I need to filter this list by checking checkboxes.

I can receive results, but they are not what I want, when I click on checkbox MEN and checkbox LARGE SIZE, all the images for MEN and LARGE SIZE are shown. But what I want is when click on checkbox MEN and checkbox LARGE SIZE, show only the specific images with this criteria. Not show all.

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination'],)
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $mdSidenav) {
    // User Information
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.userData = [{
        "id": "1",
        "family": "Submariner",
        "name": "Submariner",
        "model": "Oyster, 40 mm, Oystersteel",
        "gender": "Men",
        "size": "Large size",
        "material": "Oystersteel",
        "dial": "Dark dial",
        "pic":"/Data/Sites/1/media/watch/m114060-0002-desktop.jpg",
        "link":"https://www.sweecheong.com.my/rmcm114060-0002"  
    },{
        "id": "2",
        "family": "Oyster Perpetual",
        "name": "Oyster Perpetual 34",
        "model": "Oyster, 34 mm, Oystersteel",
        "gender": "Women",
        "size": "Mid-size",
        "material": "Oystersteel",
        "dial": "Coloured dial",
        "pic": "/Data/Sites/1/media/watch/m114200-0020-desktop.jpg",
        "link":"https://www.sweecheong.com.my/rmcm114200-0020"
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "family": "Oyster Perpetual",
        "name": "Oyster Perpetual 34",
        "model": "Oyster, 34 mm, Oystersteel",
        "gender": "Women",
        "size": "Mid-size",
        "material": "Oystersteel",
        "dial": "Coloured dial",
        "pic": "/Data/Sites/1/media/watch/m114200-0021-desktop.jpg",
        "link":"https://www.sweecheong.com.my/rmcm114200-0021"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "family": "Oyster Perpetual",
        "name": "Oyster Perpetual 34",
        "model": "Oyster, 34 mm, Oystersteel",
        "gender": "Women",
        "size": "Mid-size",
        "material": "Oystersteel",
        "dial": "Dark dial",
        "pic": "/Data/Sites/1/media/watch/m114200-0023-desktop.jpg",
        "link":"https://www.sweecheong.com.my/rmcm114200-0023"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "family": "Oyster Perpetual",
        "name": "Oyster Perpetual 39",
        "model": "Oyster, 39 mm, Oystersteel",
        "gender": "Men",
        "size": "Large size",
        "material": "Oystersteel",
        "dial": "Coloured dial",
        "pic": "/Data/Sites/1/media/watch/m114300-0003-desktop.jpg",
        "link":"https://www.sweecheong.com.my/rmcm114300-0003"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "family": "Oyster Perpetual",
        "name": "Oyster Perpetual 39",
        "model": "Oyster, 39 mm, Oystersteel",
        "gender": "Men",
        "size": "Large size",
        "material": "Oystersteel",
        "dial": "Light dial",
        "pic": "/Data/Sites/1/media/watch/m114300-0004-desktop.jpg",
        "link":"https://www.sweecheong.com.my/rmcm114300-0004"
    }
    ];

    $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.selected = angular.copy($scope.userData);
    };
    $scope.reset();

    // selected
    $scope.selected = [];
    $scope.genders = [];
    $scope.modelsizes = [];
    $scope.materials = [];
    $scope.dials = [];
    $scope.familys = [
        "Air-King",
        "Cellini",
        "Cosmograph Daytona",
        "Datejust",
        "Day-Date",
        "Explorer",
        "GMT-Master II",
        "Milgauss",
        "Oyster Perpetual",
        "Pearlmaster",
        "Sea-Dweller",
        "Sky-Dweller",
        "Submariner",
        "Yacht-Master"
                ];


    // when user clicks on checkbox, change selected list
    $scope.toggle = function (item, list) {
        var idx = list.indexOf(item);
        if (idx > -1) list.splice(idx, 1);
        else list.push(item);
    };

    // is item exists in list
    $scope.exists = function (item, list) {
        return list.indexOf(item) > -1;
    };

    // process user data and prepare whole places
    angular.forEach($scope.userData, function (user, key) {
        if ($scope.genders.indexOf(user.gender) == -1) {
            $scope.genders.push(user.gender);
        }
        if ($scope.modelsizes.indexOf(user.size) == -1) {
            $scope.modelsizes.push(user.size);
        }
        if ($scope.materials.indexOf(user.material) == -1) {
            $scope.materials.push(user.material);
        }
        if ($scope.dials.indexOf(user.dial) == -1) {
            $scope.dials.push(user.dial);
        }
        if ($scope.familys.indexOf(user.family) == -1) {
            $scope.familys.push(user.family);
        }
    });
})
```

```
.filter('selectedTags', function () {
    // filter to check array of eleMents
    return function (users, tags) {
        return users.filter(function (user) {
            if (tags.indexOf(user.gender) != -1) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (tags.indexOf(user.size) != -1) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (tags.indexOf(user.material) != -1) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (tags.indexOf(user.dial) != -1) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (tags.indexOf(user.family) != -1) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (tags.length == 0) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    };
});
```

```html
<div class="myDiv" ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<div class="hidden-xs" id="filter_desktop" layout="row">
<div class="rightPanel" flex="15" layout="column" style="font-size: 13px;">
<div class="filter">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="filter"><span>FILTER YOUR SEARCH</span></div>

<div class="resetFilter">
<center class="text-left"><button id="resetFilter" ng-click="reset()"><img alt="" src="http://endlessicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/reset-icon-614x460.png" style="height: 30px!important;" />RESET FILTERS</button></center>
</div>

<div class="primary">
<div class="container">
<div class="column" style="margin-left: -26px;margin-right: 395px;">
<div class="col-xs-3">
<div class="filter-menu">
<form>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div aria-multiselectable="true" class="panel-group" id="filter-menu" role="tablist">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading" id="headingOne" role="tab" style="border-top: 1px solid #c1c1c1;"><a aria-controls="collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" class="panel-title accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" role="button">STYLE</a><!-- /.panel-title --></div>
<!-- /.panel-heading -->

<div aria-labelledby="headingOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="collapseOne" role="tabpanel">
<div class="panel-body">
<div ng-repeat="item in genders"><md-checkbox ng-checked="exists(item, selected)" ng-click="toggle(item, selected)"> {{ item }} </md-checkbox></div>
</div>
<!-- /.panel-body --></div>
<!-- /.panel-collapse --></div>
<!-- /.panel -->

<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading" id="headingTwo" role="tab" style="border-top: 1px solid #c1c1c1;"><a aria-controls="collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" class="panel-title accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" role="button">MODEL SIZE</a><!-- /.panel-title --></div>
<!-- /.panel-heading -->

<div aria-labelledby="headingTwo" class="panel-collapse in" id="collapseTwo" role="tabpanel">
<div class="panel-body">
<div ng-repeat="item in modelsizes"><md-checkbox ng-checked="exists(item, selected)" ng-click="toggle(item, selected)"> {{ item }} </md-checkbox></div>
</div>
<!-- /.panel-body --></div>
<!-- /.panel-collapse --></div>
<!-- /.panel -->

<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading" id="headingThree" role="tab" style="border-top: 1px solid #c1c1c1;"><a aria-controls="collapseThree" aria-expanded="true" class="panel-title accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree" role="button">MATERIAL</a><!-- /.panel-title --></div>
<!-- /.panel-heading -->

<div aria-labelledby="headingThree" class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="collapseThree" role="tabpanel">
<div class="panel-body">
<div ng-repeat="item in materials"><md-checkbox ng-checked="exists(item, selected)" ng-click="toggle(item, selected)"> {{ item }} </md-checkbox></div>
</div>
<!-- /.panel-body --></div>
<!-- /.panel-collapse --></div>
<!-- /.panel -->

<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading" id="headingFour" role="tab" style="border-top: 1px solid #c1c1c1;"><a aria-controls="collapseFour" aria-expanded="true" class="panel-title accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseFour" role="button">DIAL</a><!-- /.panel-title --></div>
<!-- /.panel-heading -->

<div aria-labelledby="headingFour" class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="collapseFour" role="tabpanel">
<div class="panel-body">
<div ng-repeat="item in dials"><md-checkbox ng-checked="exists(item, selected)" ng-click="toggle(item, selected)"> {{ item }} </md-checkbox></div>
</div>
<!-- /.panel-body --></div>
<!-- /.panel-collapse --></div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading" id="headingFour" role="tab" style="border-top: 1px solid #c1c1c1;"><a aria-controls="collapseFour" aria-expanded="true" class="panel-title accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseFour" role="button">FAMILY</a><!-- /.panel-title --></div>
<!-- /.panel-heading -->

<div aria-labelledby="headingFour" class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="collapseFour" role="tabpanel">
<div class="panel-body" style="line-height: 31.6px;">
<div ng-repeat="item in familys"><a ng-checked="exists(item, selected)" ng-click="toggle(item, selected)">{{ item }}</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="collect_img" style="margin-left: 61px;">
<div flex-gt-md="100" style="width:100%"><md-card current-page="currentPage" dir-paginate="user in userData | selectedTags:selected  | itemsPerPage:18" style="width: 33.3%;min-height: 144px;"> <a href="{{user.link}}"><img alt="" src="{{user.pic}}" /> </a>

<center><a href="{{user.link}}"><span class="md-headline">{{user.name}}</span></a></center>
<a href="{{user.link}}"> </a>

<center><a href="{{user.link}}"><span class="md-subhead">{{user.model}}</span></a></center>
</md-card></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd suggest you work harder at creating a minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right now, there's a lot of stuff we have to skim through that is not relevant to the question.
Plus, by creating that minimal, reproducible example you're likely to find the solution to your problem.

Comment: What I need is something like this, except this fiddle runs an older version of Angular.js which my current setup doesnt support. Would be grateful if someone show me how to do a combine criteria search.http://jsfiddle.net/pcf0mn69/